add items to listview within form
When I start a form without sending information, it opens the list view correctly with the column headers.
However, when I try to open the same form to update information, the listview loses the headers. non-existent fcam and all the rest of the programming on top of the listview
normal opening without sending data
Code:
public FrmMicroConfig()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

opening with data sending
public FrmMicroConfig(string device) : this()
{

    Dispostivo dispositivo = Dispostivo.JsonDesserializar(device);

    txtDevicename.Text = dispositivo.Nome;
    txtDeviceIp.Text = dispositivo.IP;
    txtDeviceLocal.Text = dispositivo.Local;

    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Nome");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Id");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("StartBit");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Lenght");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Factor");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Offset");

    foreach (var Variable in dispositivo.Variables)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(Variable.Nome);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Id.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Startbit.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Lenght.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Factor.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Offset.ToString());
        LstdeviceVariables.Items.Add(lvi);
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}

The result of this are these two screens
Normal open:
enter image description here
Wrong Open:
enter image description here
I can't identify where the error comes from
I already tried adding the headers later and nothing
and even without adding items to the listview the result is the same
the listview does not work correctly
Any idea how this error is generated? Maybe some wrong class configuration or object type?

Remove the InitializeComponent(); method from the constructor overload! You're recreating everything this way. Your parametrized ctor already calls the default ctor ( : this() ) which calls the InitializeComponent(); method. You must only call this method once and in a Form, it must be called from the default ctor.

Also, you need to move the column headers creation part to the default ctor. Right after InitializeComponent();. Or just add them by the designer and forget that part. Just add the items in code.

I managed to make it work this way
Remove InitializeComponent()
public FrmMicroConfig(string device) : this()
{
Dispostivo dispositivo = Dispostivo.JsonDesserializar(device);

txtDevicename.Text = dispositivo.Nome;
txtDeviceIp.Text = dispositivo.IP;
txtDeviceLocal.Text = dispositivo.Local;

foreach (var Variable in dispositivo.Variables)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(Variable.Nome);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Id.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Startbit.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Lenght.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Factor.ToString());
    lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Offset.ToString());
    LstdeviceVariables.Items.Add(lvi);
}

}
I just left ":this()" at the beginning of the code.
Thanks for the answer @dr.null

In your form constructor then InitializeComponent() should be either the first or one of the first items (in fact, I'm surprised it doesn't raise an exception!).  This will ensure that all the controls are set-up as per your designer.
If you call InitializeComponent() later, as per your current code, then it will overwrite anything you set-up prior to that.
public FrmMicroConfig(string device) : this() {

    //Call    InitializeComponent first.
    InitializeComponent();
    Dispostivo dispositivo = Dispostivo.JsonDesserializar(device);

    //Now the rest of your code.
    txtDevicename.Text = dispositivo.Nome;
    txtDeviceIp.Text = dispositivo.IP;
    txtDeviceLocal.Text = dispositivo.Local;

    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Nome");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Id");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("StartBit");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Lenght");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Factor");
    LstdeviceVariables.Columns.Add("Offset");

    foreach (var Variable in dispositivo.Variables)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(Variable.Nome);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Id.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Startbit.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Lenght.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Factor.ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(Variable.Offset.ToString());
        LstdeviceVariables.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}

But what is also good practice, and to ensure less problems, is to place the InitializeComponent in your default constructor.  And if you don't want it to be called, set it to private.  So you have:
public FrmMicroConfig(string device) : this() {
  //your code
}

private FrmMicroConfig() 
{
   InitializeComponent();
}


When I start the constructor before, no data is loaded (the textboxes carried values) in this situation, none of the information is loaded and the column headers are not loaded either.

Yes, I didn't see that this wasn't the default constructor!  Funny, on the same day I picked up somebody else's code for exactly that problem!!

The default ctor needs to be public. This is the constructor that is called when designing the Form (the reason why InitializeComponent() must be there). Unless it's a Form that doesn't require a Designer (i.e., built in user code only)

The InitializeComponent method is where all your controls are created and configured. If you put code that references your controls in the constructor before the call to that method, a NullReferenceException will be thrown and the rest of the constructor will not be executed. You need to put any additional code AFTER the call to InitializeComponent.

When I start the constructor before, no data is loaded (the textboxes carried values) in this situation, none of the information is loaded and the column headers are not loaded either.
